# Format date netlify cms don't change

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, netlify, netlify-cms

I am trying to change the datetime widget in my website ( Nuxt + Netlify CMS). This is my config:

```
label: 'Publish Date',
          name: 'date',
          widget: 'datetime',
          required: true,
          date_format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
          format: 'LL',
```

But the render of this comes in this format:

```
2020-12-30T19:31:24.985Z
```

Shouldn't this work like this? Thank you

Comment: When you say "the render of this", do you mean in the CMS UI or in the final Nuxt site?

Comment: In the Nuxt site